# What's the difference between using netcat (nc) and curl for HTTP requests?

Tags: curl, http, netcat, nc

I'm using curl to request a specific URL and getting 200 OK response:

```
curl -v www.youtypeitwepostit.com
* About to connect() to www.youtypeitwepostit.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 54.197.246.21...
* Connected to www.youtypeitwepostit.com (54.197.246.21) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: www.youtypeitwepostit.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

If I save headers to file as:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: www.youtypeitwepostit.com
Accept: */*
```

and try to execute `nc` command (netcat):

```
nc www.youtypeitwepostit.com 80 < file
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy
Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 04:08:34 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I'm getting another response. What's the difference and how can I get 200 OK using `nc`?

I tried with different versions of HTTP in request header, tried to type request manually to avoid wrong CRLFs, tried to exclude optional headers. The results are similar.

Comment: send `\r\n` after each line

Comment: have tried, got 505

Comment: Have you tried, or have you actually done it?

Comment: thank you, guys, it's working. i sent special characters incorrectly, not very experienced with shell. i have one more question - why one hosts need \r\n while others don't? is it feature of web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant RFC, [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) contains the answer to your question: that each line of a HTTP request should end with CR/LF.

---

The grammar for the HTTP [Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) specifies that each header line should end with a Carriage Return character (`0x0d` in ASCII) followed by a line feed character (`0x0a`):

> ```
>  HTTP-message   = start-line
>                   *( header-field CRLF )
>                   CRLF
>                   [ message-body ]
> ```

This is expressed more clearly in the description of the [Request Line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1):

> A request-line begins with a method token, followed by a single space (SP), the request-target, another single space (SP), the protocol version, and ends with CRLF.
>
> ```
>  request-line   = method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF
> ```

Since `curl` is a specifically developed for HTTP requests it already uses the appropriate line-endings when making HTTP requests. However, netcat is a more general purpose program. As a Unix utility, it uses line-feed characters for line endings by default, thus requiring the user to ensure that lines are terminated correctly.

You can use the `unix2dos` utility to convert the file containing the request headers to use Carriage Return / Line Feed endings.

If you want to type the HTTP request by hand and have a recent version of `nc`, you should use its `-C` option to use `CRLF` for line endings:

```
nc -C www.youtypeitwepostit.com 80
```

*By the way, it’s worth noting that most popular Internet protocols (e.g., SMTP) use CR/LF line endings.*

---

Note that some web servers (e.g. Apache) are more forgiving and will accept request lines that are terminated only with a Line Feed character. The HTTP specification allows for this, as mentioned in the [Message Parsing Robustness](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.5) section:

> Although the line terminator for the start-line and header fields is the sequence CRLF, a recipient MAY recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore any preceding CR.

Comment: Thanks, it works well when I converted the file using `unix2dos`. But `-c` option of Mac's `nc` doesn't seems to work. When I add '-c' option, it prints nothing.